# I've clicked XKCD's "random" button k times and I've already seen all of them. What's the expected number of XKCD's I've seen?

Tags: probability, expected-value, bayesian, balls-in-bins, coupon-collector

This seems like a modification of the coupon collector's problem which can be stated as follows:

There are $n$ coupons total to collect. Given that the past $k$ coupons seen I've already collected (coupons are collected with replacement), what's the expected number of coupon's I've collected so far?

I'm also unsure if this problem depends on an underlying prior probability distribution on the number of coupons I've collected; if it does, can this be solved with an arbitrary distribution?

One additional part to this question: let's say after the $k$th one I collect a new coupon; what would the expected number of coupon's I've collected be then?

Comment: In other words, what is the expected value of *k* such that given *n* installments of xkcd, it takes *k* clicks of the random button before you've seen all of them? Or, given that it took *k* clicks to see all *n* them, what is the most likely value of *n*? The answer to the title in the question--"What's the expected number of XKCDs I've seen"--is easy: you've seen all of them.

Comment: No, k is fixed; for instance, I click the "random" button 10 times, and I've already seen every random one shown. Clearly, I've seen at least 1 XKCD (but not necessarily more, since I could've gotten the same one 10 times), but what's the expected number I've already seen?

Comment: Ooooooh, so you're asking "I know $n$ XKCDs, say of $N$ total, but I don't know how many I know. If after randomly sampling $k$ XKCDs, they're all ones that I know, what is the expected value of $n$"?

Comment: Yes, exactly; I edited to question to clarify.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know the answer from context, but just to clarify for myself: the random button draws with replacement, correct?

Comment: Interestingly enough, seeing as Xkcd uses sequential numbering for each comic, you could alternatively look at this problem as a version of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem

Comment: Yes, the random button draws with replacement; this is similar to the German tank problem, but the logic from that cannot be used, as I might've seen the most recent XKCD while not seeing earlier ones.

Comment: Are you ignoring comic 404?

Comment: You are also assuming that the random function is not the one from https://xkcd.com/221/, I suppose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you've seen $n$ comics out of $N$, the probability that $k$ consecutive comics are all ones you've seen is $(\frac nN)^k$, which is proportional to $n^k$ (the $N^k$ denominator is constant). So if the prior odds are uniform, the posterior odds that you've seen $1, 2, \dots, N$ comics are
$$
   1^k : 2^k : 3^k : \cdots : N^k.
$$
So the conditional probability that you've seen $n$ comics out of $N$ is $\frac{n^k}{1^k + 2^k + \cdots + N^k}$, and we get an expected value of
$$
   \frac{1 \cdot 1^k + 2 \cdot 2^k + \dots + N \cdot N^k}{1^k + 2^k + \cdots + N^k}.
$$
This doesn't simplify particularly well, but when $N$ is large compared to $k$, we may approximate the sum by an integral; the numerator is approximately $ \int_0^N x^{k+1}\,dx = \frac{N^{k+2}}{k+2}$ and the denominator is approximately $\int_0^N x^k \,dx = \frac{N^{k+1}}{k+1}$.

So the expected total number of comics you've read, given that you've sampled $k$ comics and you've read all of them, is approximately $\frac{k+1}{k+2} N$.

Comment: You have a minor error, the $k+1$ should become $k+2$ upon integration and same for $k$ becoming $k+1$.

Comment: Relatedly, to the next order you have $\sum_{n=1}^N n^k \approx \frac{N^{k+1}+{k+1 \choose 2} \frac{N^k}{k}}{k+1}$ which gives an idea of the relative size of $N$ vs. $k$ that is required for this integration approximation to make sense (basically you need $N \gg k$, not just $N \gg 1$).

Comment: @Ian Thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 2):

If finding  $J$ (the number of draws to collect k distinct coupons) is the goal, then  this is just Coupon's collector Problem in disguise where $k$ (number of distinct coupons you collected) acts like $n$ (total number of distinct coupons). Of course , the prior distribution matter for each type of coupon $i$;

$$  p_{i} = \Bbb P(n,i,k) = \Bbb P(i,n), $$

and the simplest case of distribution is still:

$$ p_{i} = \frac{n-(i-1)}{n}.$$ And just follow the steps in wiki link for Coupon problem but you need to sum to :

$$ \Bbb E(J|K) = n\left(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + ... + \frac{1}{n-k+1}\right)$$

BUT if you mean the number of draws $J$ is fixed and question is "What is the expectation value of $K$ : number of distinct coupons collected?" then:

$$ \Bbb E(K|J) = \sum_{k=1}^{min(J,n)}\sum_{i=1}^{n}k \Bbb P(i,k,J).$$

Up to you to find and supply $\Bbb P(i,k,J)$ which is prior distribution dependent.

We can also use Linearity of Expectation for Indicator variables $I_{i}$ indicating the existence of coupon $i$ in fixed number of draws $J$:

$$ \Bbb E(K|J) = \Bbb E(\sum_{i=1}^{n} I_{i} | J) = n \Bbb (P_{iJ})$$
where
$$ \Bbb P_{iJ} = \sum_{m=1}^{J} {J \choose m}p_{i}^{m} (1-p_{i})^{J-m}$$
$$ = 1 - (1-p_{i})^J$$
so
$$ \Bbb E(K|J) = n(1-(1-p_{i})^J).$$
And $p_{i}$ is whatever you want which is the probability of having Coupon I in fixed draws $J$ and example is $p_{i}= \frac{1}{n}$.

Let us make sense of this. For large $n$ => ($p_{i} = \frac{1}{n} << 1$):

$$  \Bbb E(K|J) \approx J$$
which make sense because most of the time if you draw J balls when the number of distinct colors is very large n, the number of distinct Balls you draw is equal to J itself: the given number of draws.

Also, we examine the case of large J:
$$ \Bbb E(K|J) \approx   n$$
which makes sense because if you draw large J then it would be very likely that you've seen all n distinct coupons.

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the random variable that counts how many distinct comics (out of the total $n$ comics) you've seen.
Let $K$ be the event "the last $k$ random comics you were shown had already been seen".

As I understand it, the problem asks for $\Bbb E(X|K)$.
We have that

$$\begin{align}
\Bbb E(X|K)
&= \sum_{x = 1}^n x\Bbb P(X = x | K)
\\&= \sum_{x = 1}^n \frac{x\Bbb P(K | X = x) \Bbb P(X=x)}{\Bbb P(K)}.
\end{align}$$

Now, $P(K | X = x)$ is easy enough to compute; that's simply $x^k/n^k$.
However, without some assumption on the underlying probability distribution of $X$, there's no meaningful way to attribute values to $\Bbb P(X=x)$ and $\Bbb P(K)$, or to their quotient.

Now, assuming we know the probability distribution of $X$ (which is discrete, and takes values on $0$, $1$, ..., $n$), then of course we know $\Bbb P(X=x)$.
Moreover, by the law of total probability,

$$\begin{align}
\Bbb P(K)
&= \sum_{x = 1}^n \Bbb P(K | X = x) \cdot \Bbb P(X = x)
\\&= \frac1{n^k}\sum_{x = 1}^n x^k \cdot \Bbb P(X = x)
= \frac1{n^k}\Bbb E(X^k).
\end{align}$$

Putting it all together we get

$$\begin{align}
\Bbb E(X|K)
&= \sum_{x = 1}^n \frac{x \cdot \frac{x^k}{n^k} \cdot \Bbb P(X=x)}{\Bbb E(X^k)/n^k}
\\&= \frac{1}{\Bbb E(X^k)}\left(\sum_{x = 1}^n x^{k+1} \cdot \Bbb P(X=x)\right)
= \frac{\Bbb E(X^{k+1})}{\Bbb E(X^k)}.
\end{align}$$

If we assume that $X$ has a uniform distribution (including $0$ or not), we recover Misha's answer.